# NSNumberFormatter not allowing more than 4 digits in UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to build a basic calculator and I'm having trouble formatting the number on the display during imput. I'm using NSNumberFormatter to put a comma after every 3 digits so that "99999" can look something like "99,999".

The problem is that it won't display more than 4 digits during input...it basically resets to 1 digit. Here is my code for the digit input:

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed: (UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *digit = sender.titleLabel.text;

        display.text = [display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];

        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
        [numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
        [numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
        [numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        NSString *theString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[display text] doubleValue]]];
        display.text = theString;
}
```

Comment: Can your code handle when the user tries to enter a zero after the decimal point? Why are you ignoring localization and setting the decimal separator and grouping separator in this way?

Answer (score 0):

These methods may come handy:

```
- (void)setMaximumIntegerDigits:(NSUInteger)number;
- (void)setMaximumFractionDigits:(NSUInteger)number;
```

You might set the maximum fraction digits to 6, or whatever you need:

```
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits: 6];
```